# What is `F` in `F[_]: Sync` and where does it come from?

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, scala-cats, higher-kinded-types

I would like to use the cats-saga from that repository: https://github.com/VladKopanev/cats-saga

However I am stuck on that piece of code at [`OrderSagaCoordinator.scala L160`](https://github.com/VladKopanev/cats-saga/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/com/vladkopanev/cats/saga/example/OrderSagaCoordinator.scala#L160):

```
def apply[F[_]: Sync: Concurrent: Timer: Sleep: Parallel](
    paymentServiceClient: PaymentServiceClient[F],
    loyaltyPointsServiceClient: LoyaltyPointsServiceClient[F],
    orderServiceClient: OrderServiceClient[F],
    sagaLogDao: SagaLogDao[F],
    maxRequestTimeout: Int
  ): F[OrderSagaCoordinatorImpl[F]] =
```

What is `F`, where does it come from, can someone explain that piece of code ?

Thanks

**Edit:** I know what a generic type is. However in that case the `apply` method is called without specifying the concrete type and I do not see any places where it came from.

```
(for {
      paymentService <- PaymentServiceClientStub(randomUtil, clientMaxReqTimeout, flakyClient)
      loyaltyPoints  <- LoyaltyPointsServiceClientStub(randomUtil, clientMaxReqTimeout, flakyClient)
      orderService   <- OrderServiceClientStub(randomUtil, clientMaxReqTimeout, flakyClient)
      xa             = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO]("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql:Saga", "postgres", "root")
      logDao         = new SagaLogDaoImpl(xa)
      orderSEC       <- OrderSagaCoordinatorImpl(paymentService, loyaltyPoints, orderService, logDao, sagaMaxReqTimeout)

    // ...
```

Comment: `F` is a generic type _(a type constructor or a rank 1 type to be more precise)_, where it comes, from right there: `def apply[F[_]` in the method definition. - Humble opinion, if this confuses you then maybe diving deep into advanced concepts like tagless final would be a bad idea; maybe it will be better to start from the beginning understand how **cats** works, then looking into **cats-effect** using concrete `IO`, and then look into tagless final.

Comment: `apply` is now just a generic method. Let's say you have `def foo[A](a: A) = ???` How to say what `A` is and where it comes from? `A` is a type parameter, it will be either specified explicitly or inferred from the parameter `a` upon a call: `foo[...](...)` or `foo(...)`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I will probably try to understand the concepts deeper.

Comment: @DmytroMitin thanks. But I know what a generic is. I have added one edit in my question.

Comment: @gervais.b `OrderSagaCoordinatorImpl(paymentService, ...)` is `OrderSagaCoordinatorImpl.apply(paymentService, ...)` so `F` will be inferred. It's known that the `paymentService` has a type `PaymentServiceClient[F]` with some specific `F`. So this `F` will be inferred in the call `OrderSagaCoordinatorImpl.apply[...F...](paymentService, ...)`.

Comment: Indeed, but there is no concrete type of `F` in `PaymentServiceClientStub` : `class PaymentServiceClientStub[F[_]: Monad](logger: Logger[F],
                                            randomUtil: FUtil[F],
                                            maxRequestTimeout: Int,
                                            flaky: Boolean) extends PaymentServiceClient[F]`

Comment: @gervais.b at some point something has an already inferred _(or probably even specified)_ value for `F` and the compiler simply propagates through the whole expression. Maybe `randomUtil`? or `logger` _(which is not shown on your example)_.

Comment: That's also my understanding, the type of `F` must be specified somewhere. I will not paste the whole code but at least, we have the same understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of something concrete, say 'box of chocolates'

```
case class Box(v: Chocolate)
```

Now imagine we take away the chocolate, and make the box take any kind of element `A`, maybe box of coins, box of candy, box of cards, etc

```
case class Box[A](v: A)
```

Here we are polymorphic in the element type of the box. Many languages can express this level of polymorphism. But Scala takes this further. In the same way how we took away the chocolate, we can take away the box *itself*, essentially expressing a very abstract idea of "any kind of context of any type of elements"

```
trait Ctx[F[_]]
```

As another analogy consider the following

```
box of chocolate  -> proper type                      -> case class Box(v: Chocolate)
box of _          -> type constructor of first order  -> case class Box[A](v: A)
_   of _          -> type constructor of higher order -> trait Ctx[F[_]]
```

Now focus on `_ of _`. Here we have "something of something", which kind of seems like we have nothing. How can we do anything with this? This is where the idea of a *type class* comes into play. A type class can constrain a highly polymorphic shape such as `F[_]`

```
def apply[F[_]: Sync](...)
```

Here `[F[_]: Sync]` represents this constraint. It means that method `apply` accepts any type constructor of first kind for which there exists evidence that it satisfies the constraints of type class `Sync`. Note that type class `Sync`

```
trait Sync[F[_]]
```

is considered a higher order type constructor, whilst type parameter `F[_]` represents a first order type constructor. Similarly

```
F[_] : Sync : Concurrent
```

specifies that type constructor `F` must not only satisfy `Sync` constraints, but also constraints of `Concurrent` type class, and so on. These techniques are sometimes referred to as scary sounding

> higher order type constructor polymorphism

and yet I am confident that most programmers have all the conceptual tools already present to understand it because

1. if you ever passed a function to a function, then you can work with concept of *higher order*
2. if you ever used a `List`, then you can work with concept of *type constructors*
3. if you ever wrote a method that uses the same implementation for both Integers and Doubles, then you can work with concept of *polymorphism*

Providing *evidence* that a type constructor satisfies constraints of a type class are given using Scala's `implicit` mechanisms. IMO Scala 3 has significantly simplified the concept so consider https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/type-classes.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good explanation and definitely a confirmation of my understanding. Now I just have to figure where the concrete type is declared/inferred.

Comment: That's a beautiful explanation.